# Saving variables from same script run multiple times in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am dealing with a class project and am in need of saving different values for the same variables each time the script is run. The script takes an input picture of a lego and outputs size, color, shape. These values need to be saved in a table of any sort that when the script is run again with a different picture, all the new values are added to the "inventory" list.

Here is the bottom portion of the script. I've been trying to play with the save feature only to find that it only replaces the values for the current variables in the `.mat` every time the script is run. Hopefully this is enough to assist me. Thank you in advance.

```
size = area_width * area_length ;

%%%%%% make sure smaller dimension always first %%%%%
% width = smaller length 
% length = longer length

Cell = {Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length};

% for iterations 1:block_count
%     if Final = {Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length}
disp(Cell)

SaveData = sprintf('%s, %d, %s, %s, %s', Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length)

save('Data.mat', 'SaveData','-append')
```

Comment: The `-append` option allows you to append new variables to an already existing mat file. If this variable already exists, it will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Before running this script, do this on command line-

```
data={};
save('Data.mat','data');
```

And then-

```
SaveData = {sprintf('%s, %d, %s, %s, %s', Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length)};
load('Data.mat');
data = [data; SaveData];
save('Data.mat', 'data');
```

Comment: This helps a lot. For us to run the script with a new input each time, we are having to clc;clear the script for the script to run. I assume the presence of the old values for the variables are keeping MATLAB from running the script the second time. When we clc;clear, it seems to reset the Data.mat or overwrites with the new values. Any suggestions? Thank you for the help.